# remove node and edge label from visNetwork visualiztion and display info when click on nodes and edges

Tags: r, igraph, visnetwork

I use visNetwork to visualize my network. Below is the code (borrowed from visNetwork cran page).
My question is:

1. I don't wont to show vertices and edge label. How can I remove it from the visualization?
2. I want to show node info when I click on nodes. It seems like Whatever is in the title column of the data is displayed when I click on any nodes and edges. Is title a 'reserved' column name for click-on info display?
3. I can barely see anything when I click on any nodes. How can I change the font on click-on display? Thank you very much.

---

```
library(igraph)
library(visNetwork)
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:10, 
    label = paste("Node", 1:10),                                 
    group = c("GrA", "GrB"),                                     
    value = 1:10,                                               
    shape = c("square", "triangle", "box", "circle", "dot", "star",
    "ellipse", "database", "text", "diamond"),                   
    title = paste0("<p><b>", 1:10,"</b><br>", paste("Node", 1:10),"</p>"), 
    color = c("darkred", "grey", "orange", "darkblue", "purple"),
    shadow = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE))                  



    edges <- data.frame(from = sample(1:10, 8), to = sample(1:10, 8),
    label = paste("Edge", 1:8),                                 
    length = c(100,500),                                        
    arrows = c("to", "from", "middle", "middle;to"),           
    dashes = c(TRUE, FALSE),                                    
    title = paste("Edge", 1:8),                                 
    smooth = c(FALSE, TRUE),                                    
    shadow = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))                       


 g <- graph_from_data_frame(d = edges, vertices = nodes)
 visIgraph(g)
```

Comment: As for p.1, have you tried to comment label and/or title? 'label' makes labels on. 'title' is the same for a tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish 1. with the `font.size` argument (see below). Regarding 2., and 3., the `visNodes` documentation for `title` reads

> Default to undefined. Title to be displayed when the user hovers over
> the node. The title can be an HTML element or a string containing
> plain text or HTML.

I would imagine you can accomplish what you desire in 3 by adjusting the html within `title` as I have also done below.

```
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:10, 
                    label = paste("Node", 1:10),                                 
                    group = c("GrA", "GrB"),                                     
                    value = 1:10,                                               
                    shape = c("square", "triangle", "box", "circle", "dot", "star",
                              "ellipse", "database", "text", "diamond"),                   
                    title = paste0("<p><b style='font-size: 40px'>", 1:10,"</b><br>", paste("Node", 1:10),"</p>"), 
                    color = c("darkred", "grey", "orange", "darkblue", "purple"),
                    shadow = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE),
                    font.size = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0))                  

edges <- data.frame(from = sample(1:10, 8), to = sample(1:10, 8),
                    label = paste("Edge", 1:8),                                 
                    length = c(100,500),                                        
                    arrows = c("to", "from", "middle", "middle;to"),           
                    dashes = c(TRUE, FALSE),                                    
                    title = paste("Edge", 1:8),                                 
                    smooth = c(FALSE, TRUE),                                    
                    shadow = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE),
                    font.size = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
```